# Multiple Select statements into an Insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've been searching for a while and I'm not sure if this is allowed in mysql.

I know this is allowed in mysql

`Insert into 'table' (column1, column2, column3) Select val1, val2, val3 From sometable`

Also this

`Insert into 'table' (column1, column2, column3) Values (val1, val2, val3), (val1, val2, val3)`

I am not sure if this is allowed though:

`Insert into 'table' (column1, column2, column3) Select val1, val2, val3 From sometable, Select val1, val2, val3 From sometable`

Obviously that gave me an error, is that allowed in mysql?

Comment: try `select .... UNION ALL select ...` just a hunch, never tried it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it, and it will fail.  Use `union all` instead of `,`:

```
Insert into table (column1, column2, column3)
    Select val1, val2, val3 From sometable
    union all
    Select val1, val2, val3 From sometable;
```

I assume the single quotes were there for some sort of effect, because you say that the first two queries actually work.